# Construction a harmonic function

Tags: complex-analysis, harmonic-analysis, harmonic-functions

Suppose $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ is a smooth, positive, bounded function on $\mathbb{R}$. Construct a real-valued continuous function $u$ on $\overline{\mathbb{H}}$ which are harmonic on $\mathbb{H}$, such that $u|_{\mathbb{R}} = f$ and $u(i) = 0$, where $\mathbb{H}$ is $\{z : Im(z) > 0\}$ }

I don't know how to construct, and I also feel confused: Suppose $u$ exists, then we consider the function $u\circ h$, where $h=\frac{i(w+1)}{1-w}$. So $u\circ h$ is defined on $D$ with positive value on $\partial D$, and $u\circ h(0)=u(i)=0$, then by mean value property, we deduce a contradiction.

Comment: Are you sure that such a function exists

Comment: Well it does exists, for example $f(x, y) = 1-y$ is such an example with $f = 1$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a Schwarz problem.

Just as you mentioned, first of all, find a holomorphic function $g$ in $\mathbb{H}$, such that $\Re\left(g\right)$, when restricted on $\mathbb{R}$, is identical to $f$. This can be done by
$$
g(z)=\frac{1}{\pi i}\int_{\mathbb{R}}\frac{f(x)}{x-z}{\rm d}x.
$$
If $f$ is merely bounded but not integrable, you may use
$$
g(z)=\frac{1}{\pi i}\int_{\mathbb{R}}\frac{f(x)\left(z-z_0\right)}{\left(x-z\right)\left(x-z_0\right)}{\rm d}x
$$
instead, where $z_0\in\mathbb{H}$ could be arbitrarily chosen.

So far, this $g$ yields that $\Re\left(g\right)$ is bounded in $\mathbb{H}$, which satisfies the mean-value property.

Secondly, consider
$$
h(z)=g(z)+iKz,
$$
where $K\in\mathbb{R}$ will be determined by the constraint $\Re\left(h\right)(i)=0$. This $\Re\left(h\right)$ will be the very function you are looking for.

Comment: But where did I go wrong?

Comment: @Danny: Since $u$ could be unbounded when $z\to\infty$, when you maps $\mathbb{H}$ to $\mathbb{D}$, $u\circ h$ could witness a singularity somewhere on $\mathbb{\partial D}$. This makes the mean-value property no longer applicable. You may use the example from user "John Ma", $f(z)=\Re\left(1+iz\right)$ to check for this.

Comment: But with finite singularities on $\partial D$, the mean-value property still works

Comment: @Danny: Well, if you put it in this way, you must count in the $\infty$ as well. Say some $v$ is harmonic in $\mathbb{D}$. When restricted on $\partial D$, we have $v=1$ except for the point $z=1$, where $v$ witnesses a singularity, i.e., $v\to\infty$ as $z\to 1$. In this case, the maximum of $v$ on $\partial D$ should be $\infty$ rather than $1$, and thus the values of $v$ in $\mathbb{D}$ could exceed $1$.